# Disable browser toolbars, menu bars etc when the page loads

Tags: javascript, window, toolbar

I am trying to figure out a way to disable toolbars, scrollbars etc when the page loads, using JavaScript or ASP.NET.

i know i can use this

```
window.open('default.aspx', 'google', 'height=800px,width=480px,location=no,toolbar=0,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
```

but I dont want to open a new window but rather i want to apply these settings to the current window.

Regards,
MNK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word: Impossible without a browser plug-in

Why do you want this anyway? For a school's intranet where students do competitions on who can install the most toolbars in one hour?

Answer (score 1):

window.open() is pretty much your only option unless you write a full-screen plugin or create an app with a browser embedded in it.